# 'You might know'-suggestions in social networks

Tags: social-networking

I have three main models. Users, photos, and relationships.

The relationship model consists of two fields = from_user, to_user. When userA (from_user) follows UserB (to_user), I would like to display other accounts that are similar to userB to userA. userA will be more inclined to follow accounts that are similar to userB. What method should I implement in order to come with this list of similar accounts?

The first example that I could immediately think of was Instagram & Twitter which show similar accounts right after you follow a user. I was thinking perhaps the suggested accounts that they show are the result of multiple set intersections.

Doing set intersections between all of the "following" sets of UserB's followers might be a possible solution. This would generate a set showing all the common users that UserB's followers follow. When this set is presented to userA, userA might also be inclined to follow people on this set since userB's followers also follow them. My logic here is that userB's followers might share a common interest. This common interest is probably one of the reasons why they followed userB in the first place. It is very likely that userB's followers might also follow other accounts similar to userB.

The whole reason for why I even started thinking about this is because of a question I found on [Quora](http://www.quora.com/How-does-the-people-to-follow-suggestions-algorithm-work-on-services-like-Facebook-Instagram-or-Twitter) the other day.

One user mentioned:

*1. The people who the people you follow follow.  The overwhelming majority of my use for Twitter is following media people to know what they're working on.  Most of the suggestions are accounts that they follow.*

*2. Matched e-mail.  Someone you know uploaded their address book or e-mail activity for "mining" and you were on the list.  LinkedIn really seems to like this one, because most of the recommendations are people I don't actually know, but I briefly interacted with them via e-mail years back.*

As some of you have suggested, this is probably an open ended question, but I decided to give it a crack on stack to see what other implementations some of you have employed. If this question is not fit for stack overflow, please help me direct it to somewhere it would be, perhaps another stack exchange community.

Thank you

Comment: I think this question is too open-ended as you can use many many many different methods to find 'you might know' or 'you might be interested in` users. You could compare posted material, you could use shadow profiles like Facebook does, you could compare who has whose phone numbers, email addresses....

Comment: thanks @ThomWiggers. I kind of had a feeling this question would be open-ended and out of scope for stack overflow, know any other place where I could perhaps get answers? perhaps an IRC channel or some other exchange community?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after scouring through the Internet, I realized Facebook has a pretty good resource as to how they make their "People You May Know" lists:

https://www.facebook.com/help/501283333222485/

I think I have a pretty good starting point. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the Graph Theory concept of [Strongly Connected Components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component). Your model can be thought as directed graph where the vertices correspond to users and the edges are the "follow" relationships.

[image: Strongly connected components]

Observing the graph above. If "user b" follows "user c", the it would be reasonable to recommend "users d and h", which are in the same strongly connected component of "user c".

This approach was suggested by Tim Roughgarden in his Introduction to Algorithms course on Coursera (as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11212772/474671)).

You could use a similar approach with other kinds of directed or undirected relationships like "studied with", "worked with", etc to find the users that are most likely "similar".